# How to extract the characters specifying the particular position?

Tags: scripts

for example: file 1

```
Line 1: FHEAD0000000001UPINV20180821033550
Line 2: THEAD00000000020000000001MRCHI 0962691                       SUPP  212055    20180820000000   8709385  

Output: 8709385
```

This is a position delimiter file. I need a Unix command to get the character in line 2 (95-102).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want a range of characters *and* a specific line, I'd suggest Awk:

```
awk 'FNR==2 {print substr($0,95,102-95)}' file1
```

If you just wanted a range of characters for every line, you could have used `cut -c95-102`